# Difference between console and carbon in WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using `WSO2 IdentityServer` 5.11.0 version. After starting the server, I found that two URLs are appearing :

1. https://localhost:9443/carbon
2. https://localhost:9443/console

What is the difference between the two URLs? Looks like they are solving the same purpose but have a different UI. Please help me to clear the ideas of these two URLs.

Answer (score 3):

https://localhost:9443/console URL is for the newly released react-based console application (https://github.com/wso2/product-is/releases/tag/v5.11.0)

https://localhost:9443/carbon URL is for the old management console.

Both applications' purpose is the same. Still, the react-based console is in the BETA version. So, some functionalities in the management console may not be available in the console application.
Whatever change you do in one application should be reflected in the other.

Comment: With the WSO2 IS 7.0 release, the old carbon portal is deprecated and new react based Console is the default management portal.