# Unable to delete service provider in wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have seen two service providers added to my wso2 installation.

As I try to delete any of the service providers I get an error

```
Error while removing application: Deletion of system applications are not allowed. Application Name: XXX
```

I have logged in from admin user and still, I am not able to delete it

I tried giving permissions of service provider explicitly to the admin user but still the same error

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are using IS 5.11.0 above.
Conosle and MyAccount are the two systems apps available in the IS pack. It doesn't allow to modify/ delete the system apps.

- Console is the newer portal for administrative tasks.
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/65733363/10055162
- MyAccount is the newer version of
  previous user portal/ dashboard.

So deleting these apps are **not recommended**.

Anyhow, If you want to remove both Myaccount and Console apps out of the readonly apps (allow to modify the app configs/ delete the apps), use the following config.

```
[system_applications]
read_only_apps = []
```

Then restart the server. You will be able to do configuration changes now. Refer:

- https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/setup/migrating-what-has-changed/#configurable-system-apps
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/68167283/10055162